# Is there any limit for Post Length for SOLR?

Tags: solr

im using SOLR but for some reasons im missing some of my docs.

I want to know is there any limitation for HttpPost?
or Solr Docs per each commit?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of post lies actually more on the server side than on the solr side. If you put solr into tomcat, the it's the limit of tomcat's post which usually interest you, if you put your tomcat behind apache or nginx, then their max post size will also interest you.

as for post itself, http spec doesn't have any limit. Most of the Time it's the server which limits it.

Comment: thank you Rowanto so i should find the post limitation of jetty :)